# An application of maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to do some problems in complex analysis in a book **zill and shanahan** and the question was about  *maximum modulus* and it was asked to find maximum modulus of the function $(*):$$f(z)=z^2+2z-3$ in the region $|z|=1$
now my confusion is that in a worked example which is similar to the function above  $f(z)=z^2+5z-1$ in the same region $|z|\leq1$ they processed as ;
$|z^2+5z-1|\leq|z|^2+5|z|+|-1|$

> Since the maximum modulus of $f$ occurs  on $|z|=1$,the inequality shows that the maximum modulus of $f(z)=z^2+5z-1$ over the region is 7.

Now my question is that why can't we apply the similar procedure to $(*)$ so that maximum modulus would have been 6 Then , instead of $\frac{8}{√3}$ (given)

Comment: That quoted statement about $z^2+5z-1$ is wrong.  The inequality shows that the maximum is **at most** $7$.  The actual maximum is $\sqrt{29}$.

Comment: I'd personally represent the function in terms of $e^{i\theta}$ and maximize the modulus with respect to $\theta$ though I imagine there's something a bit more elegant than that. I'm a simple man. I see max/min, I differentiate.

Comment: @Robertisreal ,I just copy this  from _ zill_ , I don't know any other way to find the maximum modulus can you suggest me any easier method